# Stop Nivo Slider Autoplay and start slide on specifc action?

Tags: jquery, nivo-slider

How can I make Nivo slider start only when I click on a specific link or go to the specific dot slide and stop there. (by dot I meant number of slide (nivo-controlNav))

Thank you!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I'm reading you correctly, here's how I figure it.

When you set up Nivo set the `manualAdvance` property to `true`. That will set Nivo to only transition when the nav is clicked.

[See the documentation here](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/support/jquery-plugin-usage/)

So it would be something like:

```
$('#slider').nivoSlider({
    // Your settings here
    manualAdvance:true
});
```